# activate VoiceOver via code

Tags: iphone, accessibility

UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning() tells me if VoiceOver is active, but if it were not I wish I could turn it on. Is there a way?

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe there is a way to do this. Even if there was this would be a tarrible idea. I'm a blind Ipod user who uses Voiceover on a regular basis. When ever I let a sited person borrow my Ipod I have to make sure to turn Voiceover off since using Voiceover changes most jestures to have a different meaning. If you need Voiceover to be enabled for a specific reason I suggest you display a message to the user explaining why Voiceover needs to be turned on with instructions on how to do so. If the user will need to toggle Voiceover on and off frequently instructions for setting the tripple click option to activate and deactivate Voiceover would be helpful.